# Android HttpPost socket timeout when android goes to sleep in background service

Tags: android

I have an android app that uses a background service for uploading data.

When we go upload data, everything works fine.  Even when we make the display sleep, everything works.

However, this was while we were connected to Eclipse via USB.  Once we disconnected the device, started to send the data and made the screen 'sleep,' we got a socket timeout exception.

Is there a special setting in the Service I need to make to allow it to continue to send data when the display sleeps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a special setting in the Service I need to make to allow it to continue to send data when the
>   display sleeps?

You need to hold a `WakeLock`. And, if you are connected via WiFi, you will need to hold a `WifiLock`.

Comment: I see, I need a partial wake lock.  Thanks Mark, you da' man!